# Shopify: How place Multi currency Form in 2 places (in Header & in MobileMenu - for responsive design)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, shopify

We are trying to add **Shopify's 'Multi Currency**' feature *  to their '**Supply**' theme.
We had it basically working, but as we need responsive design the Currency drop-down needs to be:

- a) in the header (next to the Cart button) - for wide screens, and
- b) in the NavMenu - for mobiles.

We added the shopify multi currency code in 2 places, but got duplicate errors,
so changed the Form names so didnt conflict, but still got duplicate errors at lower level.

How should it best be done/put in 2 places?

Nb Shopify introduced it in 2018, it's now end-2020 but they don't seem to have applied it to their own themes!

Below are excepts of our code from the header.liquid file:  (the inserted code is wrapped in comments containing "###" )

```
  <div class="grid-item large--one-half text-center large--text-right">
    {% if section.settings.show_announcement or shop.customer_accounts_enabled %}
      <div class="site-header--text-links{% if section.settings.announcement_text == blank %} medium-down--hide{% endif %}">
        {% if section.settings.show_announcement %}
          {% if section.settings.announcement_link != blank %}
            <a href="{{ section.settings.announcement_link }}">
          {% endif %}

            <p>{{ section.settings.announcement_text | escape }}</p>

          {% if section.settings.announcement_link != blank %}
            </a>
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if shop.customer_accounts_enabled %}
          <span class="site-header--meta-links medium-down--hide">
            {% if customer %}
              {% capture first_name %}<a href="{{ routes.account_url }}">{{ customer.first_name }}</a>{% endcapture %}
              {{ 'layout.customer.logged_in_as_html' | t: first_name: first_name }} &middot; {{ 'layout.customer.log_out' | t | customer_logout_link }}
            {% else %}
              {{ 'layout.customer.sign_in' | t | customer_login_link }}
              <span class="site-header--spacer">{{ 'layout.customer.or' | t }}</span>
              {{ 'layout.customer.create_account' | t | customer_register_link }}
            {% endif %}
          </span>
        {% endif %}
      </div>

      <br class="medium-down--hide">
    {% endif %}

    <!-- Multi-currency selector form added ###                      -->
    <div id="formInMain">
        {% form 'currency' %}
            {{ form | currency_selector }}
        {% endform %}
    <!--   end multi-currency form, but the wrap div is closed below -->


        <a href="{{ routes.cart_url }}" class="header-cart-btn cart-toggle">
          <span class="icon icon-cart"></span>
          {{ 'layout.cart.cart' | t }} <span class="cart-count cart-badge--desktop {% if cart.item_count == 0 %}hidden-count{% endif %}">{{ cart.item_count }}</span>
        </a> 
   
    {% include 'search-bar' %}        

     </div>    <!--  this is the closing currency wrapper so form & cart stay together -->
  </div>
```

---

```
<div id="mobileNavBar">
  <div class="display-table-cell">
    <button class="menu-toggle mobileNavBar-link" aria-controls="navBar" aria-expanded="false"><span class="icon icon-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span>{{ 'layout.navigation.mobile_menu' | t }}</button>
  </div>    
  <div class="display-table-cell">
    <a href="{{ routes.cart_url }}" class="cart-toggle mobileNavBar-link">
      <span class="icon icon-cart"></span>
      {{ 'layout.cart.cart' | t }} <span class="cart-count {% if cart.item_count == 0 %}hidden-count{% endif %}">{{ cart.item_count }}</span>
    </a>

    <!-- Multi-currency selector form added ### -->
    <div id="formInNavBar">
      {% form 'currency' %}
      {{ form | currency_selector }}
      {% endform %}
    </div>
    <!--   end multi-currency form -->

  </div>
</div>

<nav class="nav-bar" id="navBar" role="navigation">
  <div class="wrapper">
    {% include 'search-bar' %}
    {% include 'mobile-nav' %}
    {% include 'site-nav' %}
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I have it working now - it was a completely spurious error - another element was over the drop-down which was preventing it from getting focus!    But I would still like to know if there is a better way of coding having the form in 2 places.

Comment: Well it works, but I still get an error if I validate the html (at validator.w3.org). I get  "Error Duplicate ID 'currency_form' ".     And "Error Duplicate ID 'MenuParent-6' ".  How should I code to remove these errors?